# API Key for Amazon Cognito Sync Demo

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use this sample application code: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo

There is an 'api_key' (in asset directory)

Where can I generate or get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api_key is for Login with Amazon integration. From the [README](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/README.md):

6. To add support for Login with Amazon. (Optional)

   - Follow the instructions at https://login.amazon.com/android to register a new application

     - For "Label", enter Cognito sync demo
     - For "Package Name", enter com.amazonaws.cognito.sync.demo
   - Make sure your identity pool is configured to support Login with Amazon by entering the Client ID at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/ from the previous step.
   - Copy and paste the API key to assets/api_key.txt
   - If this isn't configured properly, the "Login with Amazon" button will be disabled in the sample app.